# Android: Convert pdf to images

Tags: android

i m receiving a **pdf** file from the server & want to display it as images..

So is der a way to convert this pdf file to Images?

**UPDATE:**

Can i do this thru [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html)?
If not, how can i do this thru PDFBox API???

Thanks,
Nital Shah

Comment: I need the same too.. will be following this thread!!

Answer (score 2):

Your probably better off converting the pdf files on the server so that the mobile device doesn't have to do the intensive processing.

So the mobile device will to a http request for the image and just fetch the image (whereas the server processes the pdf files on demand or in bulk)

The conversion on the server can be done with ImageMagick libraries.